# Update a database with external API data in django

Tags: python, django, web

I'm learning Django for a project I'm working on and I'm having a problem implementing this part, basically I want my this to happen:

1. The user enters a term into a search box
2. The server queries a public API and adds some of the data to the database

I have my model set up with a form in the view. So I can get the search term from the post request. However I'm unsure how to then use that to gather the data and save it to the database.

The model is just a list of basic fields:

```
fileName = models.CharField(max_length=120)
rating = models.FloatField()
date = models.DateField()
```

The form is just a text box for the fileName:

```
class searchFile(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = file
    fields = ['fileName']
```

I can work out how to gather the data from the API myself, I'm more confused about how to input data to the database from the code rather than directly from the form.

For instance how could I make it so that when a user inputs a fileName into the form, fileName is input into the database and all the other fields are filled with random data?

Comment: In it's current state your question is very difficult to answer. What does your model look like? What does "some of the data" mean? What format is the data in (believe or not some API's still use XML)? PLease add some of your code to your question as well as any errors you are receiving and what exactly you would like the result to be.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply and sorry for the confusion, I've added a bit more detail to my question.

Comment: Perhaps this doc can help you a bit https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/forms/

Comment: @user2320239 do you updated the database from an external API ? Please share if you got the solution.

Answer (score -1):

once you have your data from your API, you can update your Django model by using the save() function. this is an example of what i've done.

def home(request):
    api_key = "your_api_key"

```
# sports api response
sports_response = requests.get('https://api.the-odds-api.com/v3/sports', params={
    'api_key': api_key
})

sports_response_json = sports_response.json()

#loop through the list to update the database

for sports in sports_response_json['data']:
    sports_update = Sport(name=sports['key'])
    sports_update.**save()**

sports_objects = Sport.objects  # getting all the job objects
return render(request, 'home.html', {'Sports': sports_objects})
```